# i want to get only date from datetime variable in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get only date from datetime variable. I was using this code. It was working fine but now I am facing problem when I'm trying to store only date in mysql please. Take a look at the code below and please tell me what I'm missing,

```
$date_time = "11-Dec-13 8:05:44 AM"
```

From the date I got from user input, I need to save only date in `att_date` variable.

```
$arr = explode("/", $date_time);
$arr2 = explode(" ", $arr[2]);
$att_date = $arr2[0].'-'.$arr[0].'-'.$arr[1];
```

Comment: what is `$date_time`? if it is `11-Dec-13 8:05:44 AM`, why are you exploding on `"/"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
$date_time = "11-Dec-13 8:05:44 AM";
$new_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($date_time));
```

Comment: i am sorry i don,t know how to give you vote?? please advise me i definite give you and like your post.. i

Answer (score 1):

Even if you just use `"Y-m-d"` it will work instead of using `"Y-m-d H:i:s"`,please practice below example:

```
$datetime = '2022-10-11 06:38:02';
$getOnlyDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($datetime));

echo $getOnlyDate;  // output: 2022-10-11
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it, especially if you answer a pretty old question that already has an accepted answer

Comment: ....and especially if the code, when executed, does not print what it should. `strtotime` returns a timestamp, for your example it returns `1665446400` and not `2022-10-11`

Answer (score -1):

You can get the date from the datetime variable using the

> Date();

function from mysql using php query, it automatically extracts the date from it. You can learn it [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date.asp)

Comment: Please share more details. If the string `11-Dec-13 8:05:44 AM` is already present, why should MySQL be used to convert this string to another one?